# vim ctags setup

Tags: vim, installation, ctags

I have my project in the following path: `~/work/my-proj`. Inside the project folder I created a `.proj-ctags` folder and issued the following command to create the tag file:

```
ctags -a -R -f .proj-ctags/.tags --exclude=@./.proj-ctags/ctags-exclude-list *
```

In my `~/.vimrc` I also added the path to the tags file. When I open a file in `~/work/my-proj` and press `Ctrl-]` by having the cursor on a function name or variable name, I get

```
E257: cstag - tag not found.
```

Can some one let me know whats wrong in my setup?

Thanks for your time.

Cheers...

Comment: What is the output of `:set tags?`?

Comment: @RandyMorris: the output is tags=~/work/my-proj/.proj-ctags

Comment: It should point to .proj-ctags/.tags

Comment: So the tags file name cannot be anything but .tags? Is that right?

Comment: arumug: see `:help 'tags'`.  The `tags` option is a list of filenames, not directories.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`cstag` is a cscope-related command. Some plugin must have remapped `C-]` to `:cstag` because normally, it runs `:tag` instead.

Do you use cscope as well as ctags?

Could you tell us what `:verb map <c-]>` tells?

Comment: :verb map <c-]> gives "No mapping found". How to find out whether vim is using cscope or not? The reason I ask this is - .vimrc doesnt have any mention of cscope at all.

Comment: So, what does `:verb set cst?` tell you?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. ':verb set cst?' returned cscopetag which is being set from /etc/vimrc. Thanks, that explains it.

Comment: errrr... I'm in the same situation as the OP. How do I get the ctags keys to work, and prevent cscope from interfering? cscope is being loaded in /etc/vimrc which I cannot change.

Comment: The solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7038533/2136640) fixed it for me.