# cscope error when trying to use ctags in vim

Tags: vim, ctags, cscope

I have generated ctags for my projects:

```
ctags -f /home/grae/tags --recurse --langmap=C++:.C.h.c.cpp.hpp.inl --languages=C++ --extra=+q --fields=+iaS --c++-kinds=+p --verbose framework/ modules/ /usr/include/
```

I then added the tags to .vimrc:

```
set tags+=/home/grae/tags
```

I also temporarily added the following (but have now removed):

```
set csto=1
```

Now when I try Ctrl+] or g] I get the error:

cstag: tag not found

I shouldn't be using cscope so I'm not sure how this has happened. My current thoughts are:

```
* cscope on by default
* something has overriden Ctrl+] and g]
```

Any ideas how to solve this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Found an answer when inspecting :options, you need to turn off cscope by using:

```
:set nocst
```